# Another way to say, finding the right one?

Tags: idioms, synonyms, learning

I'm trying to build a learning material about interviewing and hiring tips. I'm thinking of a catchy title that appeals to the general corporate audience. Something that everyone gets but is not corny. I've thought of Finding the Right One but I've already used that with the previous interviewing course I built for another company. I'm thinking of using "Searching High and Low" but I'm also open to better suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about: Finding the perfect match?